# Phonegap Canvas2Image plugin black screen

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-canvas, phonegap-plugins

I have a project I am creating in phonegap 3.1, that I'm running into an issue with. The project ultimately will need to work on android and IOS, but for the moment, I'm only trying to get the android version working.

After much fiddling, I have been able to get the canvas2image plugin to write a 2d canvas to a png in the picture folder, however when I view the file, the file is all black. The canvas is not being written, only a black image.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/canvas2image.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">             
        $(document).ready(function() {              

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="saveImg" onclick="saveImg();">Save Image</button>
    <br />
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width=1275 height=1650></canvas> <!-- //w=1275 h=1650 -->
    <image id="theimage" crossorigin="anonymous"></image>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var canvas, context, myImg, imgCanvasPath, sources, phn, strAddy, petName, city, custName, state, zip, email;

var app = {
initialize: function () {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function () {
    //app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    app.initCanvas();
    app.buildCanvas();
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function (id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
},

initCanvas: function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    phn = "000111";
    strAddy = "111 Anywhere Street";
    petName = "Pet Name";
    city = "Anywhere";
    custName = "Snoop Dawg";
    state = "CA";
    zip = "55555";
    email = "inthedoghouse@email.com";
    myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

},

buildCanvas: function () {
        //header
        context.font = 'bold 40pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('CLAIM FORM', 40, 150); //left, top


        context.font = '12pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('Fill out one claim form per pet. Submit itemized, legible invoices. Incomplete claim submissions may delay claim processing.', 40, 180); //left, top

        //Body
        //black square
        context.rect(40, 220, 30, 30); //left, top, width, height
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fill();

        context.font = 'bold 14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#FFF';
        context.fillText('1', 49, 242); //left, top

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(40, 250);   //position at left, angle or if equal to bottom value, pos from top
        context.lineTo(1200, 250);    //position at right, angle 
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.stroke();

        context.font = 'bold 18pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('POLICYHOLDER INFORMATION', 80, 242); //left, top

        context.font = 'bold 18pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('POLICY NUMBER:', 80, 300); //left, top

        //policy # - var
        context.font = '14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(phn, 300, 300); //left, top

        context.font = 'bold 14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('ADDRESS:', 600, 300); //left, top

        //street addy - var
        context.font = '14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(strAddy, 710, 300); //left, top

        context.font = 'bold 18pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('PET NAME:', 80, 350); //left, top

        //pet Name - var
        context.font = '14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(petName, 220, 350); //left, top

        context.font = 'bold 14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('CITY:', 600, 330); //left, top

        //city - var
        context.font = '14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(city, 710, 330); //left, top

        context.font = 'bold 18pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('NAME:', 80, 400); //left, top

        //Name - var
        context.font = '14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(custName, 170, 400); //left, top               

        context.font = 'bold 14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('STATE:', 600, 360); //left, top   

        //state - var           
        context.font = '14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(state, 710, 360); //left, top

        context.font = 'bold 14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('ZIP:', 950, 360); //left, top 

        //state - var           
        context.font = '14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(zip, 1000, 360); //left, top

        context.font = 'bold 14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText('EMAIL:', 600, 390); //left, top   

        //state - var           
        context.font = '14pt Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(email, 710, 390); //left, top
}, 

saveImage: function () {
        window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg) {
           imgCanvasPath = msg;
            alert("imagePath: " + " " + msg);
        },
        function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },

        canvas
    );  

}

};

function saveImg() {
    app.saveImage();
}
```

So when the png is outputted, a black image is created, and none of the "canvas" is included. I'm pretty stumped on this, and am hoping it's just a simple error, (perhaps I'm not outputting the canvas to another div or something?).

Hoping someone else has a suggestion for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm encountering this same issue. Did you ever figure it out?